# how to match the same characters from the lists in a list and export the results separately

Tags: list, for-loop, while-loop

guys! I get a list(final_word_list), and I'd like to match the same characters from all the sub-lists under the list named "texts_under_directory", and export the result separately, shown as the picture [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14f2Ax_8afEKiAZhdu-iUaC0bbNWhXdEp/view).

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

final_word_list = ['zero', 'two', 'four', 'six', 'eight', 'ten', 'twelve', 'fourteen', 'sixteen']

texts_under_directory = [['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'], ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'], ['eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen']]

# texts_under_directory[0] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
# texts_under_directory[1] = ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
# texts_under_directory[2] = ['eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen']

final_result = []

i = 0
while i < len(texts_under_directory):
    for b in texts_under_directory[i]:
        for a in final_word_list:
            if a == b:
                for x in word_tokenize(b):
                    final_result.append(x)

    print(sorted(set(final_result)))

    i += 1
```

The output is:

```
['four', 'six', 'two']
['eight', 'four', 'six', 'ten', 'two']
['eight', 'four', 'six', 'ten', 'twelve', 'two']
```

My expected output is:

```
['four', 'six', 'two']
['eight', 'six', 'ten']
['eight' 'ten', 'twelve']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the answer myself. I just leave it below.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

final_word_list = ['zero', 'two', 'four', 'six', 'eight', 'ten', 'twelve', 'fourteen', 'sixteen']

texts_under_directory = [['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'], ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'], ['eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen']]

# texts_under_directory[0] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
# texts_under_directory[1] = ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
# texts_under_directory[2] = ['eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen']

n = 3
final_result = [[] for _ in range(n)]

i = 0
while i < len(texts_under_directory):
    for b in texts_under_directory[i]:
        for a in final_word_list:
            if a == b:
                for x in word_tokenize(b):
                    final_result[i].append(x)

    print(sorted(set(final_result[i])))

    i += 1
```

The Output

```
['four', 'six', 'two']
['eight', 'six', 'ten']
['eight', 'ten', 'twelve']
```